# How to post nested JSON body request swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a payment request JSON  format, How can I convert to a json object
 to post in Swift URLRequest.

```
{
"createTransactionRequest": {

    "merchantAuthentication": {

        "name": "YOUR_API_LOGIN_ID",

        "transactionKey": "YOUR_TRANSACTION_KEY"
    },

    "refId": "123456",

    "transactionRequest": {

        "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",

        "amount": "5",

        "payment": {

            "opaqueData": {

                "dataDescriptor": "COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT",

                "dataValue": "PAYMENT_NONCE_GOES_HERE"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: For uploading, you don't want a JSON object. You want JSON data. It looks like that's what you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `URLRequest` object. Set it's type to POST. Set the contents to your JSON. Use the URLRequest to create a `URLSessionUploadTask`. Pass the `URLSessionUploadTask` to a `URLSession` for uploading.

See this link from Apple's developer site for a more detailed explanation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/posting_data_to_a_website

Comment: How can I create json object body for that above json format. ?

Comment: can i use { instead of [ ] }

Comment: let params =   "createTransactionRequest": [
                "merchantAuthentication": [
                    "name": "xxxxxxxxxx",
                    "transactionKey": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
                ],   "refId": "123456",
                "transactionRequest": [
                    "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
                    "amount": "1",
                    "payment": [
                        "opaqueData": [
                            "dataDescriptor": desc!,
                            "dataValue": token! ] ]
]
            ]

Comment: Save your `JSON` data to a file in the app bundle. Get a URL to the file using the Bundle method `Bundle.main.url(forResource:withExtension:)`. Then read the file using `Data(contentsOf:options:)`.

Comment: use this -> let params = ["createTransactionRequest": [ "merchantAuthentication": [ "name": "xxxxxxxxxx", "transactionKey": "xxxxxxxxxxx" ], "refId": "123456", "transactionRequest": [ "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction", "amount": "1", "payment": [ "opaqueData": [ "dataDescriptor": "desc", "dataValue": "token" ] ] ] ]]